# Internet disappears after few minutes

Tags: wireless, networking, internet

I have a strange issue. I moved to another city with different Internet and now after being connected to Wi-fi for few minutes (~5) Internet stops working, but wi-fi is still connected. Disconnecting and connecting back does not help - no Internet. The only thing that works is to turn off networking completely and then turn it back on. After this procedure I can to connect to wifi with Internet, but Internet works only for several minutes and then I lose it again. A very strange issue, I never had it before (using Linux for ~10 years). Btw wifi works perfectly fine on Chromebook. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Here is [my info](http://pastebin.com/sLKAy595) generated using the script from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos).

```
Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

~$ iwconfig

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"BLABLA"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 68:EF:BD:2D:BE:A3   
      Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=61/70  Signal level=-49 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: Is "Chromebook" a completely different computer? Or a program/OS on this computer? If it's a different computer, maybe there's something incompatible about your wifi adapter and the "new" router here...? i.e. can any OS stay connected on this hardware?

Comment: Chromebook is a completely different computer. I will install Windows to see if it works.

Comment: On Windows Internet also disappears every few minutes, but I do not need to turn off networking, I can just reconnect.

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-
what-can-i-do>

Comment: @WildMan Sure, thank you! I am attaching it to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few things that we can change to help your connection. First you have many networks in your area so their is a lot of channel congestion. Go into your router and try channel 2,4, or 9. We usually recommend 1,6 or 11 but to many other people are using those channel. Set encryption to just wpa2 AES personal not TKIP. Then save your router configuration.

Go into network manager top right corner of the screen and change IPV6 to ignore then reboot.

Edit:
Run

```
sudo iwlist scan
```

that will show all networks available find the Mac Address of the network you want to connect too then open network manager and put the Mac Address in the BSSID column, save the setting of network manager then reboot computer.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to the router. Also I tried to ignore IPv6, it did not help.

Comment: I added more directions for you to try, that should work.

Comment: Unfortunately specifying MAC has no effect.